# Insert operation with many-to-many relationship using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I've two model classes:

```
public class Candidate
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext name is JobsContext.

The above code generates me 3 tables Candidates, Jobs & CandidatesJobs(autogenerated by EF)

Now I've records in Jobs table : Id = 1, Name = "Sales" : Id = 2, Name = "Engineer".

I want to associate a new Candidate which I'll be inserting into Candidates table with the 2 records from Jobs table.

Before inserting the Candidate I know the Id's of the Jobs table & I don't wish to make a call to the database to get more details from Jobs table.

How do I do this using Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about this?

```
Job salesJob; // already fetched from db
Job engineerJob; // already fetched from db

Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
candidate.Name = "John Doe";
candidate.Jobs = new List<Job>(); // you could also do this in the constructor of Candidate
candidate.Jobs.Add(salesJob);
candidate.Jobs.Add(engineerJob);

context.SaveChanges();
```

This only works if you already fetched the jobs from the database within the same instance of the `DbContext`, else EF will think that the jobs are 'new' and tries to insert them. If you only have the ids, you could try the following:

```
var salesJob = new Job { Id = salesJobId };
var engineerJob = new Job { Id = engineerJobId };

context.Jobs.Attach(salesJob);
context.Jobs.Attach(engineerJob);

candiate.Jobs.Add(salesJob);
candiate.Jobs.Add(engineerJob);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @cbeckner how about if you call `context.Jobs.Attach(new Job { Id = salesJobId  });` first?

Comment: thanks for answering. Well I tried the second code you entered above EF creates a new entry with Id 3 & 4 into the Jobs table containing null values and associates those Ids with that particular candidate. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonahPereira I just updated my answer with the `Attach()` calls, did you also try that?

Comment: yes that did the trick!! & exactly what i wanted. Thanks @HenkMollema

Comment: @JoSmo that should get you the same result. As long as both entities are attached to the current database context.

Comment: @HenkMollema thank you. I deleted my previous comment by mistake, so here it is: "Does it matter if you add the Job to the Candidate or the other way around (add Candidate to Job)? Or do you get the same result?"

Comment: How to do if I'm using repository pattern and working on service? because jobs and candidate exist in their own services

Answer (score 7):

There are two options.

If you are going to have the same context and candidate objects laying around, you can simply add the existing candidate objects to the job.
For example:
Create your candidates and save them to the database:

```
JobsContext context = new JobsContext();
var candidate1 = new Candidate() { Name = "John Smith" }; //id 1
var candidate2 = new Candidate() { Name = "Jane Smith" }; //id 2
var candidate3 = new Candidate() { Name = "John Doe" }; //id 3
context.Candidates.Add(candidate1);
context.Candidates.Add(candidate2);
context.Candidates.Add(candidate3);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Then, create your job:

```
var job = new Job() { Name = "Good Job" }; //id 1
```

Finally, add your candidates to the new `job` variable, add the job to the context and save changes.

```
job.Candidates.Add(candidate1);
job.Candidates.Add(candidate2);
context.Jobs.Add(job);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**OR**

If you are using a DIFFERENT context from the one you created the candidates with, then you can create a new candidate object and attach it to the context prior to adding it to the job.

```
//different context from above example
JobsContext newContext = new JobsContext();
//this can be a new or existing job, using the job from the example above here
var existingJob = newContext.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == 1);
```

Create our candidate object by setting **only** the ID

```
var existingCandidate3 = new Candidate() { Id = 3 };
```

Attach the object to the new context.  *Note: if the context from the example above is still around, it will not let you do this since it is already tracking the candidate.*

```
newContext.Candidates.Attach(existingCandidate3);
```

Set the state to Unchanged since we don't want to create a new candidate, just use the existing one.

```
newContext.Entry(existingCandidate3).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Add it and save the changes.

```
existingJob.Candidates.Add(existingCandidate3);
newContext.SaveChanges();
```

Done!

Comment: In the 1st option your making 2 database calls 1)to insert the candidate 2)associate the candidate with the job. **I was hopping to do it on one INSERT itself**, like JobsContext.candidates.Add(candidate) which contains an existing job. Refer : [link](http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.in/2012/03/entity-framework-insert-operation-with.html)

Comment: You can remove the `SaveChanges` call after creating the candidates in the first example and make one call to `SaveChanges` after you have created both the candidates and the job.  However, EF will still translate this into several distinct database calls (at *least* one for each table).  Your question made it sound like you wanted to avoid a `SELECT` against the candidates table prior to adding them to the job.

Comment: I fexed the code to correct the state change, was missing the 'Entity' into your code: the correct is System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged

Comment: "If you are using a DIFFERENT context from the one you created the candidates with" you mean a different object of the same context (`var a = new context1();var b = new context1();`) or a different context (`var a = new context1();var b = new context2();`)?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to create a VIEW of the xref table exactly as the table (view_tablename_raw). Then update that view in EF as an entity without foreign keys. From their use *context*.view_tablename_raw.Add(...) and it will work seamlessly.