# How can i add new value Secondary table in Many to many relations of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, rdbms

i have 3 table. 2 of them has got many to many relations. Last one is secondary table like that:

Student:
id-------   Name-------        SurName 
1--------    fsfsf----------       fsfsfsdf
2--------    dfdsf --------      sfsfsdfsdf

Course

id----------Name-------
11--------    course1----------
22--------    course2--------
23--------    course3--------

StudentCourse

Studentid---------CourseId
1-------------------11
1-------------------12
2-------------------22
2-------------------23
2-------------------11

But Secondary table is hidden inside of the Entity framework model. But i need to add Studentid and Courseid  without any changes of Course and Student table. How can i achive that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 5 - INSERT OPERATION MANY TO MANY RELATIONSHIP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130983/entity-framework-5-insert-operation-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fluent-API to map your relation table. To achieve that, you have to edit the OnModelCreating method like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
   .HasMany<Student>(c => c.Students)
   .WithMany(s => s.Courses)
   .Map(m => {
       m.ToTable("StudentCourses");
       m.MapLeftKey("CourseId");
       m.MapRightKey("StudentId");
    });
```

Don't forget to do an "update-database" command on your Package Manager.