# How to insert a model in ef 6 with a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, many-to-many

The question im asking is closely related to:

[Insert operation with many-to-many relationship using EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130983/insert-operation-with-many-to-many-relationship-using-ef)

The big difference between that question and mine, is how would I do this from a web api perspective.

Essentially i want to post to a MVC Web API 2 endpoint a json string along the lines of

```
{"Name":"Job3","Candidate":[1,2,3]}
```

to an end point like:

```
POST: api/Jobs
```

And have it recognize that i want to create a job 3, which has an association with Candidate 1, 2, and 3.

EDIT:
The answer given so far, deffinitly allows me to continue but...

If possible I would like to do this using the scaffolding methods created when using visual studio. For example

```
public Job Post(Job JobFromBody){
....
}
```

*Note: i don't actually care how the json looks, also if theres a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Im not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(JobRequest request) 
{
    // ... model validation, other checks

    // create job object
    var job = new Job { Name = request.Name, Candidates = new Collection<Candidate>() };

    // associate existing candidates to the job
    foreach(var candidate in request.Candidates) {
        var c = new Candidate { Id = candidate.Id};
        context.Candidates.Attach(c);   // without this, EF will try to create new Candidate
        job.Candidates.Add(c);    // associate the existing candidate with the job
    }

    context.Jobs.Add(job);      // add the job
    context.SaveChanges();      // save

    // ... handle errors, return status codes etc.

}
```

Comment: `JobRequest` vs `Job` - is that it? You can change your json to match the properties of `Job` and model binding will take care of rest.

Comment: So how would the model binding accept a list of Candidates(what would the java object look like). I guess the idea here is i should have a step where i validate, and have a step where i add the job(inserted as a paramter) directly into the `context.Jobs.Add(job);` If thats not possible you can just say so.

Comment: It can be an array of the Candidate Ids, like in your example.