# Create EF Core One-To-Many Relationship data through asp.net core POST

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I have this simple model:

```
public class Form
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<FormField> FormFields { get; } = new List<FormField>();
}
```

```
public class FormField
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller method:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Form item)
{
    EntityEntry<Form> entityEntry = Context.Add(item);
    ModuleContext.Database.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(entityEntry.Entity);
}
```

When I now post something like that:

```
{
  "Name": "Test Name",
  "FormFields": [
    {
      "Name": "Field Name",
      "Value": "Field Value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Only the `Name` of the Form is set but no new Form Field is created. Even the "item" returned by `FromBody` only contains Form.Name but FormFields are empty.

How can I create multiple FormFields through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly `Form.FormFields` is always empty list no mater what the input is. If that's the case the reason behind it is that `FormFields` does not have setter and cannot be set. Try adding `set;` for `FormFields` (not 100% sure but `private set;` should be sufficient)

Comment: Yes the lack of setter can be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - for understaning there is relation:

**One Form have multiple FormFields**

---

There is properly configured relationships?

```
modelBuilder.Entity< Form >()
    .HasMany(c => c.FormFields)
    .WithOne(e => e.Form);
```

---

If this json don't add the element to database properly:

```
{
  "Name": "Test Name",
  "FormFields": [
    {
      "Name": "Field Name",
      "Value": "Field Value"
    }
  ]
}
```

then there is an option for add the FormFields and Name seperately:

```
EntityEntry<Form> entityEntry = Context.Add(item);

foreach(field in item.FormFields){
   EntityEntry<FormFields> entityEntry = Context.Add(field);
}

ModuleContext.Database.SaveChanges();
return Ok(entityEntry.Entity);
```

---

Also reference for many to many:

[How to insert a model in ef 6 with a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258090/how-to-insert-a-model-in-ef-6-with-a-many-to-many-relationship)